# PersistenceException when I was using Ebean in Play framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1, ebean

I am writing a web application in Java by using Play Framework 2.1.0. And I am using Ebean to manipulate the database. But I got one problem now:

I have a model class called book with an int type column called page:

```
    public int page;

    @Column(name="page")
    public int getPage() {
        return page;
    }

   public void setPage(int page) {
        this.page = page;
   }
```

And the page column in my MySql database is also int type. When I get a result(row) using Ebean and the value of page column in my database has a specified value like 12, it works well. But if the value of page attribute is null in my database, the application will throw an exception:

```
Execution exception[[PersistenceException: Error loading on models.Book.page]]
```

I don't how to deal with this problem.

Comment: Could you use a try-catch?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use an `Integer` wrapper, that can be null, instead of `int` primitive:

```
public Integer page;

@Column(name="page")
public Integer getPage() {
    return page;
}

public void setPage(Integer page) {
    this.page = page;
}
```

Then you will be able to get\set nulls

Comment: You are my saviour, thanks a lot!